# What does (s *)0 in (size_t)&(((s *)0)->m) mean

Tags: c++

This is one of the series of macros in stddef.h.

```
#define offsetof(s,m)   (size_t)&(((s *)0)->m)
```

What does (s *)0 mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof

Comment: It should be noted that the behaviour of this is undefined and you should not use this kind of thing in your program. Some compilers implement offsetof with a built-in instead.

Comment: Just to clarify: the behavior of `offsetof(type,member)` is defined by the C++ standard (C++11 18.2/4), but only when `type` is a *standard-layout* type and `member` refers to a non-static data member. This particular implementation of `offsetof` relies on behavior that is not defined by the standard but by the specific C++ implementation. In other words, using `offsetof` in your code is perfectly ok, but dereferencing a NULL pointer in your code - like this implementation of `offsetof` is doing - is not portable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a way of writing a `NULL` pointer of type `pointer-to-s` . By taking the address of the `m` member of an `s` whose address is 0, you get the offset of `m` within an `s`.

Comment: BTW, doesn't `((s *)0)->m` invoke undefined behavior?

Comment: @Nawaz: But this has a very well defined behaviour: it gives you the "object" m that is a member of the structure s which resides at the memory location 0. The undefined behaviour would be any read- or write-access to m or s. (The most likely behaviour in that undefined case would be a memory access violation, which would cause the program to crash immediately — unless the OS does not forbid any access to that address range in memory.)

Comment: @comonad: I'm speaking from the language point of view, not what the compiler does with your code. I'm sure the language doesn't allow this!

Comment: @Nawaz -- Note that this example comes from `stddef.h`. I realize that's not proof of anything, but it shows how accepted the technique is. I'm pretty sure it's legal, because as @comonad says, all we do is compute the address: we don't use it for anything.

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm really sure that c++ allows that; I guess Java does not. In c++, there would only be a problem with this, iff m were in the virtual table of s. (Like a virtual function or anything in one of the virtual superclasses of s.) If you were right, then what would you do on embedded systems without memory restrictions or even actual memory structures at address 0, like in DOS?

Comment: @comonad: Java? How you can even speak of Java here! Anyway, in C++, lots of things which are dear to many programmers, are actually undefined behavior (UB)! It doesn't really matter if something (which is UB) works on all the compilers. It is still UB.

Answer (score 3):

It's a typecast, converting `0` to `pointer to s`.

Comment: It is to note that you should use `static_cast` or one of the C++ casts instead.

Comment: @Jeffrey stddef.h is used for both C and C++, so it doesn't use C++-specific features.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cast to an `s` pointer. `s` in this case is one argument to the macro and hopefully a type name.

Comment: Hopefully a structure type name.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pointer of type `s` and ẁith value zero (null)

Answer (score 0):

s is supposed to be a type name here, such as `int`, so `(s*)0` is basically casting `0` to a pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

`0` is not only the integer zero but also the null pointer. Therefore `((S*)0)` cast the null pointer to a pointer to `s` (where `s` is probably a struct).

Comment: In this case, it's more important that it's 0. It's not being used as a null pointer.